# About Python input and split errors

Tags: python

My code

```
a = input().split(" ")

print(a)
```

input

```
1 2 3
```

but i'm getting `['1', '2', '3/usr/local/bin/python3'..etc]`
Why does it return `/usr/local/bin/python3` along with the output?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Can you show how you call Python to get this output?

Answer (score 0):

```
pbryan@dynamo:~$ python3
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 12 2021, 17:14:51) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = input().split(" ")
1 2 3
>>> print(a)
['1', '2', '3']
>>>
```

Comment: So, what is the solution to this?

Comment: Try using the interpreter as I did. Hopefully it will work the way it did for me. If it still occurs in your case, can you paste the whole interaction, so I can see how it's being invoked, and what's being typed?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you don't end your input with spacebar. Worked for me.

Comment: When your input ends with a space, do you get the same error as OP?

Comment: Yes, I didnt dug deeper in to this, just remembered not to end my input with space. Probably this can be easily fixed with _replace(" ", "")_